# Android Studio- extras.putString(); not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send parameters from one Activity to another using Intent and  extras.putString(); from one activity and trying to fetch the values in another and set that value in the Textview field.

My code looks like this:

PAActivity.java

```
Fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFirst);
Lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLast);
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
Fnameholder = Fname.getText().toString();
Lnameholder = Lname.getText().toString();
emailHolder = email.getText().toString();
phoneHolder = phone.getText().toString();

Log.e("phoneHolder",phoneHolder);

submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(PAActivity.this,DisplayActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("F_NAME", Fnameholder);
        extras.putString("L_NAME", Lnameholder);
        extras.putString("EMAIL", emailHolder);
        extras.putString("PHONE", phoneHolder);
        myIntent.putExtras(extras);
        PAActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

DisplayActivity.java

```
name = new TextView(this);
email = new TextView(this);
phone = new TextView(this);
name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
    first = (String) extras.get("F_NAME");
    last = (String) extras.get("L_NAME");
    Nameholder = "my name is "+first+" "+last;
    name.setText(Nameholder);
    emailHolder = (String) extras.get("EMAIL");
    email.setText(emailHolder);
    phoneHolder = (String) extras.get("PHONE");
    phone.setText(phoneHolder);
}
```

The problem here is that, the intent is loading the second activity but the setText does not seem to work. I am not able to see the values being set in the Textviews. Could someone please help?

Comment: What if you use `extras.getString()` instead of `(String) extras.get()`? And does a `extra.hasKey()` check return `true`?

Comment: Also the `new TextView(this);` lines are unnecessary as you're re-declaring them with `findViewById()` immediately afterwards.

Comment: Try to use `putExtra()` method on Intent directly, and `getStringExtra()` to get the String. So `intent.putExtra(someString)` and `someString = intent.getStringExtra()`.

Comment: In DisplayActivity.java, remove the first 3 lines. You don't need to instantiate a new TextView or any kind of view. You do it correctly by using `findviewById`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your submit.onClick() function you should pull the values of the EditTexts again. You want the last value to be sent when the User hits submit. I think you might be putting in an empty string because you're not pulling the values in your onClick

Comment: Good catch, in the code above only the default values of the various `EditText`s are going to be passed into the `Intent`.

Comment: Also, an easy way to check if this is true is simply using Log.d() to print out the values that you are passing into your setText call.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, it worked, when it fetched the values in onclick.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some other answers, you need to get the values of the `EditText`s inside of your `onclick` method. Your PAActivity should now look like this:

```
/* Depending on what the rest of your code is, 
* you may be able to remove the lines of code leading up to the 
* `submit.setOnclickListener`, and only have it inside of the `onClick` method.
*/

Fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFirst);
Lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLast);
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
Fnameholder = Fname.getText().toString();
Lnameholder = Lname.getText().toString();
emailHolder = email.getText().toString();
phoneHolder = phone.getText().toString();

Log.e("phoneHolder", phoneHolder);

submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFirst);
        Lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLast);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        Fnameholder = Fname.getText().toString();
        Lnameholder = Lname.getText().toString();
        emailHolder = email.getText().toString();
        phoneHolder = phone.getText().toString();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(PAActivity.this,DisplayActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("F_NAME", Fnameholder);
        extras.putString("L_NAME", Lnameholder);
        extras.putString("EMAIL", emailHolder);
        extras.putString("PHONE", phoneHolder);
        myIntent.putExtras(extras);
        PAActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Also, as I mentioned in a comment on your question, this is what your new DisplayActivity.java should look like:

```
name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
    first = (String) extras.get("F_NAME");
    last = (String) extras.get("L_NAME");
    Nameholder = "my name is " + first + " " + last;
    name.setText(Nameholder);
    emailHolder = (String) extras.get("EMAIL");
    email.setText(emailHolder);
    phoneHolder = (String) extras.get("PHONE");
    phone.setText(phoneHolder);
}
```

Comment: Yes Micheal, Thank you! Changed it and got my values.

Comment: @Dhirish great! If this answer helped you please upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the values in the `onClick` method from the `EditText` views.

If you do not fetch the value in the `onClick` then it will pass the default values to DisplayActivity.java, which is what is happening to you.